# Валидация входящих пропсов FC, useState

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hужно сделать правильную валидацию входящих пропсов. Со строкой `id` нет никаких проблем. А вот `setList` - функция хука useState, которaя должна принимать массив таких обьектов -

```
interface ZapisiI {  
  _id: string; 
  field1?: string;
  field2?: string;
  field3?: string;
  date?: string;
}
```

Я перепробовал много всяких вариантов и не представляю как реализовать проверку этой сущности по правильному. У меня выскакивают 2 такие ошибки в строке с `setList(zapisi);`:

1. This expression is not callable. ts(2349)
2. Type 'AppointmentI[]' has no call signatures.
   А сами компоненты выглядят так: 
   **`Zapisi.tsx`**

```
const Zapisi = () => {
  const [list, setList] = useState < ZapisiI > [];
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const zapisi= await store.getZapisi();
    setList(zapisi);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

return (
    <ModalEdit setList={setList} id={id} />
  )
}
```

**`ModalEdit.tsx`**

```
interface ModalEditI {
  id: string;
  setList: AppointmentI[];
}

const ModalEdit: FC<ModalEditI> = ({ id, setList }) => {
..... в предыдущем компоненте переменная "list" содержит старый массив записей
    setList(zapisi); // zapisi массив объектов таких как обозначено выше
.... а теперь предыдущий компонент содержит переменную "list" с новым массивом записей
}

ModalEdit.propTypes={
  []: {AppointmentI}[]
}

export default observer(ModalEdit);
```

Какие нибудь мысли как это решить?
Спасибо.

Comment: ты объявил `setList: AppointmentI[];` как массив, но пытаешься вызвать его как функцию ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Да, я не знаю как правильно там написать

Comment: просто посмотри какой тип у функции, которую возвращает `useState`

Comment: добавь в вопрос пример где ты используешь `ModalEdit` чтобы было видно что и как ты передаешь

Comment: В родительском компоненте где объявлена эта переменная `  const [list, setList] = useState < AppointmentI > [];`  ошибок не светит. А в этом в ModalEdit светит эти ошибки

Comment: отредактировать вопрос можно с помощью кнопки [edit] под вопросом.

Comment: Добавил больше кода

Comment: `useState < ZapisiI > [];` вот так не может быть написано

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138833/discussion-between-grundy-and-segvr).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

const [list, setList] = useState <Array< ZapisiI >>([]);

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]